# Confusion about subscript vs superscript statement

Tags: tensors

The author of a book on Tensor algebra and analysis makes this statement.

"The sense of the index changes (from superscript to subscript or vice versa)  if it appears under the fraction bar."

Can someone clarify this for me?   What fraction bar?

[image: The last highlighted line]

Comment: Apart from the small favor of making the question readable, who is the author of the book, and what's the title? Without context, it's very difficult to explain isolated passages. (Best to make it read horizontally, possibly even retyping for the benefit of your readers...)

Comment: I did type the quote of interest in the question.  The book is by M.  Itskov,  Tensor Algebra and Tensor Analysis for Engineers.  Also,  the image was rotated by the website. It appears correct in my machine.

Comment: Ah, good. It is correct in my browser now, too. Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: No problem at all.   Thanks for letting me know.   I appreciate all input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they are trying to explain the following convention:

Say you have an expression like $$a^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$ We have one upper index, plus an upper index in the denominator. We view the latter as being a lower index, so the amount of upper and lower indices still match, making the net index still zero. In particular, an upper index in the denominator is considered a lower index.

Comment: So that expression *would* be summed according to the Einstein convention since one is a superscript and the other is "considered a subscript" then?   Why on earth wouldn't one just write the denominator term as a subscript in this case? Two conventions that interfere with each other??

Comment: Yes, it would. And that's just the convention; the superscript being on the bottom is viewed as being a subscript. We could remove the fraction and use alternative notation- we could also write $a^j\partial_{x_j}$, or just $a^j\partial_j$, if the coordinates are obvious. What I wrote is a pretty common notation for tangent vectors and vector fields, though.

Comment: Also, it is pretty helpful when we're doing things like changing coordinates. For example, the change of coordinates on a manifold from $(x^1,\cdots, x^n)$ to $(y^1,\cdots, y^n)$ is given by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}.$

Comment: Thanks.   Earlier in the book the author showed a similar summation to 1.5 in the image above,  but the scalar was listed first and the vector second.   They both had subscripts.  Is this some other convention or is the choice of sub vs super arbitrary?

Comment: If they hadn't introduced the convention yet, they might've just been neglecting it. It kind of depends on the context. The general idea is that superscripts relate to elements of the dual space and subscripts to the original space. For example, I might have an element $x= \alpha^i e_i,$ where $e_i$ is a basis for whatever vector space $x$ is in, and $\alpha_i$ are the coordinates. You can check by applying the dual basis $f^k$ to the above that, in fact, $\alpha^k=f^k(x),$ so the notation does, indeed, represent elements of the dual.